# Adding Buttons to an image using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am developing a game using pygame and have set a background image as the welcome screen, I would like to be able to add a button on the background image such that onclick of that button takes you to another view.

Any assistance will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use image (or Sprite) as button (I named it `image_button`).

In main loop when you get `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event you can get mouse position `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` and then check if it is inside `image_button` rectange `image_button.get_rect()`.

And

```
WELCOME_SCREEN = True

while True:

    # --- events ---

    if WELCOME_SCREEN:
        # - get events 
        # - compare mouse position to image_button rectangle
        # - change WELCOME_SCREEN to False

    # --- changes ---

    # --- draws  ----

    if WELCOME_SCREEN:
       # draw welcome screen
    else:
       # draw view

    pygame.display.update()

    # --- FPS ---
```

If you need more - show your code.